# writing an angularjs directive to wrap other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've little experience writing my own directives.

In my app I've been implementing my own tabs like this:

```
<div id="tab_1" ng-class="{'active': selected == 1}" ng-click="selected = 1"></div>
<div id="tab_2" ng-class="{'active': selected == 2}" ng-click="selected = 2"></div>
<div id="tab_3" ng-class="{'active': selected == 3}" ng-click="selected = 3"></div>
```

With the content like this:

```
<div id="tab_1_content" ng-class="{'active': selected == 1}"></div>
<div id="tab_2_content" ng-class="{'active': selected == 2}"></div>
<div id="tab_3_content" ng-class="{'active': selected == 3}"></div>
```

It works fine, but I feel like, instead of having that same `ng-class` and `ng-click` everywhere, I could just wrap this functionality in a directive. Could somebody explain how that would work, and possibly demonstrate the best practice for doing something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you eventually want is this:

with tab-content being a directive that attaches the necessary html. So in a template you would define:

```
<div ng-class="{'active': selected == 1}" ng-click="selected = 1">
  <div ng-class="{'active': selected == 1}" ng-click="selected = 1"></div>
</div>
```

As for defining directives, check out http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html and the angularjs home page, they actually have a tab example.

What seems strange is that the click event shouldn't have to be repeated, the parent div should record the click event. So now we would have in the template is:

```
<div ng-class="{'active': selected == 1}" ng-click="selected = 1">
  <div ng-class="{'active': selected == 1}"></div>
</div>
```

And what you could do to remove the second ng-class directive is define in css:

```
.active div { your styles here }
```

So you would end up with:

```
<div ng-class="{'active': selected == 1}" ng-click="selected = 1">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: There are no parent divs with the tabs. The tab button and the tab content are separate in the html. But I see why you were confused - I made a mistake typing the question. There aren't supposed to be click listeners in the content divs. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample directive.  In your case, you want to substitute simpler html for more complicated html.  What is in the template is what is replacing the simpler html.  The restrict is saying that you are using element tags, transclude is allowing the content of the tag to carry over, scope is the attribute you are using.

```
HTML:
<my-wrapper value="1">Alpha</my-wrapper>

Javascript:
myApp.directive('myWrapper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            value: '@'
        },
        template: '<div id="tab_{{value}}_content" ng-class="{\'active\': selected == {{value}}}" ng-click="selected = {{value}}" ng-transclude></div>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C1ph3r/2p88D/

Because selected wasn't shown to be declared, you might have to expand this example to complete the interactivity.  The template can be further expanded if you need to nest another div inside of the first.

Comment: Hmm, this is ok for OPs particular case, but what if they didn't want to use this as a tag, only attributes (therefore `restrict: 'A'`).